# HOW TO add/give full height to parallels columns divs with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem adding 2 divs in parallel and giving them a full height.

i already have the divs in parallel, but the problem is when i want to give them the full `height:100%;` it happens nothing.

Which properties do i have to change to make possible this??

The idea is to have a cover page, without x-scrollbar and y-scrollbar, only a cover photo, divided

this is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/davidlerma87/3u8v01b4/2/

Well

**First:** As you can see, i have a menu bar on top that actually is not working well.

**Second:** I want below 2 parallels columns with full height

**Third:**  this is for mobile too.

**The problem is the position of the divs that are misaligned
regards and thanks!!**

[image: see screenshot here]

**Again quick explanation, 
screen divided in two columns but with full height including the top menu**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this fiddle, I have made necessary changes in css

```
html,body { height:100%; }
body {
    background: url("img/GProxpt.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color:#f1f3f5;  
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size:14px;
}

.container-fluid {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 0; */
    /* left: 0; */
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 100%;
    /* overflow: auto; */
}

.icon-menu {    
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:7em;
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:30px; 
    height:40px;
}

.icon-menu:hover {
    width:35px; 
    height:45px;
}

.row-menu { background:red;     min-height: 100%;}

.left-side {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-left:20px;
    margin-top:7em;
}

.left-side .title {
    color:#DCEA5F;
    font-size:50px;
}

.left-side .title .sub-title {
    font-size:35px;
}
.left-side .text-par {
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:0;
    font-size:20px;
}

.cols {
        /* position: absolute; */
    display: block;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.outer-right-side {
    position:relative;
    background:#18232E;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-top:0;
}

.outer-left-side {
    margin-bottom:0;
    position:relative;
  background:white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3u8v01b4/5/

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/51wwmvqx/
Removed the scrolls and made HTML structure changes.

Comment: tahnk you man, but is not working well... i modified the screen shot added. if you wish you can take a look again. regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.cols {
   height: 100vh; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the div is expanded, but there is an overflow scrollbar and i dont want it

Comment: May b this would be helpful for you,

For removing the scroll you can apply this CSS on body:

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}